# Can the media controls of the standard MediaElement control be modified?

Tags: uwp

I'm using the MediaElement control in my UWP app. I want to modify the controls that are by default showed. Can I do that?

Comment: can you show an example of what you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please review how to ask good questions on http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please refer to [Create custom transport controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) and the official [Media transport controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls). If you still have any question about it, please post your code and specify what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. It depends on what you want to customize though. The key is the `MediaTransportControls` control. And on the `MediaElement` you must set `AreTransportControlsEnabled` to `True`.

To determine the simple style settings like Compact or Full controls or to determine which button is shown, there are properties on the `MediaTransportControl`. For instance:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True" IsFullWindowButtonVisible="True"  />
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

If you want to style the controls (other glyphs, colors, animations, etceteras) you must copy the default Style template for the control and modify that. This is described very well in [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).